# Accessing JavaScript objects

Tags: javascript

Can someone please explain this bit of piece of code?
Thanks.

```
 alert({foo:"test foo", bar:"test bar"}.bar); // "test bar"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{foo:"test foo", bar:"test bar"}
```

This creates a new object with two properties, `foo` and `bar`. If you're used to Java or C# or C++ or a language like that, it's like saying

```
class FooAndBarObject {
  public string foo;
  public string bar;

  public FooAndBarObject(string foo, string bar) {
    this.foo = foo;
    this.bar = bar;
  }
}

new FooAndBarObject("test foo", "test bar");
```

So, then writing `{foo:"test foo", bar:"test bar"}.bar` returns the value of the `bar` property, which happens to be `"test bar"`.

`alert` is a function that displays the value passed to it, so it will display `test bar` to the user.

Answer (score 1):

1. `{foo:"test foo", bar:"test bar"}` creates a new object with two fields: `foo` and `bar`
2. `alert(obj.bar)` outputs a value of `bar` field of this newly created object

Answer (score 1):

Object literal in javascript is some kind of associative array.

Are pairs:

```
  var a  = { 
     key1: 'value1',
     key2: 'value2',
     "key #3": 'value3'
    }
```

Can contain any kind of data in values,
Key should be a strings if they contain special characters, spaces or reserved words.

Access to values of `a` can be by dot ( as in OOP):

```
 a.key1 == 'value1';
```

But if key contain special characters described above you can access to value means `a` like as associative array;

```
a["key #3"] == 'value3'
```

However,

```
a["key1"] ;
```

also is correct

Every declaration/assignment in javascript  returns the object itself or assign respectively, so:

```
var a;
(a={ 
    key1: 'value1',
    key2: 'value2',
    "key #3": 'value3',
    key4: function(){
       //`this` refers to `a` variable - if function will be called directly from `a`  => a.key4() ; 
      alert(this["key #3");}
        }).key1  // gets 'value1'
```

or

```
({ key1:'value1' })['key1'];// gets 'value1' too
```

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript the {} notation defines an object, you just get the bar property in this case. It is similar to a class in any OO language; and similar to the following code:

```
var obj = {
 foo : 'Test Foo',
 bar : 'test bar' 
};

alert( obj.bar ); //Show the 'bar' property of obj.
```

The declaration just returns itself obviously, so the syntax you showed is legal. However it is fairly useless, as you cant do anything with the object you just defined anymore.

Answer (score 0):

you have an object

with 2 properties : foo , bar.

foo value is "test foo"

bar value is "test bar"

but show me the value of bar.

{foo:"test foo", bar:"test bar"}.bar

Answer (score 0):

In your example the function `alert` is called with an object as it's parameter. The parameter constructs an object on the fly with two properties, `foo` and `bar`, then accesses the `bar` property, which returns a string for the `alert` function to display.

Answer (score 0):

You have two bits of code there:

```
{foo:"test foo", bar:"test bar"}
```

This is an object literal: it defines an object with two properties `foo` and `bar`, each of which has a string as its value.

```
.bar
```

This is the member operator: it gets a member from the object whose name is `bar`.

I can't imagine a use-case for this style of coding...

Answer (score 0):

JS creates the object and immediately displays the property bar:)
may be helpful: http://json.org/

Answer (score 0):

The syntax `{foo:"test foo", bar:"test bar"}` is called Javascript Object Notation (JSON), and it allows a javascript object to be constructed using with a much terser syntax then:

```
var obj = function() { this.foo = "test foo"; this.bar = "test bar"; };
var instance = new obj();
```

So in the above example, you are creating a javascript object with two fields, and then immediately accessing the `bar` field.